# Как уменьшить шаг итерации при обучении сверточной сети?

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Разбираюсь со сверточными сетями в Python 3.5 + TensorFlow + TFLearn.
Код [отсюда](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py#L15) работает, однако из 55000 примеров для обучения использует только каждый 64-й.
Кроме того, для каждой новой эпохи используются те же самые данные - каждый 64-й.

Как уменьшить шаг итерации так, чтобы сеть использовала каждый первый пример?
Если этого сделать нельзя, как в каждой новой эпохе использовать другие данные, а не те же самые?

Пример сообщений об обучении

```
Training Step: 1  | time: 2.416s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 -- iter: 064/55000
Training Step: 2  | total loss: 0.24470 | time: 4.621s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.24470 -- iter: 128/55000
Training Step: 3  | total loss: 0.10852 | time: 6.876s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.10852 -- iter: 192/55000
Training Step: 4  | total loss: 0.20421 | time: 9.129s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.20421 -- iter: 256/55000
```

Comment: Исходник ваш шибко большой и к тому же не по PEP8 сделан. Попробуйте изолировать проблему - вместо реальных данных взять совсем тривиальный минимальный пример (какие-нибудь выдуманные сгенерированные матрицы вместо изображений), чтобы каждый смог вашу проблему воспроизвести у себя. Может быть к этому моменту проблема решится сама собой.

Comment: @m9_psy
Для воспроизведения проблемы можно запустить [этот](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py#L15) код, который будет работать у всех. При его запуске проблема аналогична.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В действительности сеть использует каждое изображение, но выводит сообщение об обучении только для каждого 64. Этот параметр регулируется **batch_size** в **model.fit**. По умолчанию он равен 64.
Для того, чтобы показывалось каждое первое сообщение, необходимо изменить код следующим образом:

```
   model.fit({'input': X}, {'target': Y}, n_epoch=20,
               validation_set=({'input': testX}, {'target': testY}),
               snapshot_step=100, batch_size=1, 
               show_metric=True,run_id='convnet_mnist')
```